# C# Winforms timers / object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, timer

I have this code:

```
System.Timers.Timer ti1, ti2, ti3;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_1 == true)
{
    ti1 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    ti1.Interval = 1000;
    ti1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tiel1);
    ti1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    ti1.Stop();
}
}
```

It successfully works, but because I do not want to use the same code, I created a helper method:

```
private void my_timer(System.Timers.Timer tim, System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler Tick)
        {
            tim = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            tim.Interval = 1000;
            tim.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
            tim.Enabled = true;
        }
```

and then I call it `my_timer(ti1, tiel1)`

but when `ti1.Stop()` is called it gives me this error "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like they should be, but can you verify that the created timer(s) in the helper are actually running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Dmitry it is not a duplicate so please remove the downvote if you downvoted. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in c# method parameters are passed by value not by reference.

In case of your code
`System.Timers.Timer ti1, ti2, ti3;` all 3 are reference of `System.Timers.Timer` containing null values.

When you have passed `ti1` as parameter, it passed the value `null` of `ti1` so,
after executing the following expression : `tim = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);` it has the reference of `System.Timers.Timer` while `ti1` is containing null value still

So, Rearrange your `my_timer` method as following to achieve your expected behavior

```
private System.Timers.Timer my_timer(System.Timers.Timer tim, System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler Tick)
    {
        tim.Interval = 1000;
        tim.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
        tim.Enabled = true;
        return tim;
    }
```

and then trigger the method and use the returned value as following

```
System.Timers.Timer ti1, ti2, ti3;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ti1 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
   if(_1 == true)
   {
      ti1 = my_timer(ti1, tiel1)
   }
   else
   {
     ti1.Stop();
   }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should include in your answer that if you use `ref` the op will get the behavior they want

Answer (score 1):

In C#, **parameters are generally passed by value**.

Here's what it means.

When you assign a new value to a method parameter, like this:

`tim = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);`

it means that from now on `tim` will be a reference to a new `Timer`, but it does not affect the reference you passed from outside (`ti1`). So in your case `ti1` is **still a null reference**, because you never assigned any object to it.

`ti1` and `tim` **are not the same reference.** If you assign (`=`) something to one, it does not affect the other.

**Possible solution**

Instead of declaring `tim` as an argument, you should `return` the new object from the method:

`var tim = ...`

...

`return tim`

and assign the result of the method to `ti1`:

`ti1 = my_timer( ... )`

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly. I have two choices now. :D Thanks again. :)